# Set minimum delay between message - rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I need a solution where I can set a minimum delay between the messages that are polled out of the Queue. I do not want to delay every message by a fixed amount of miliseconds.

Lets say the Queue get 3 messages in the first second. But I want to pull every 5 seconds. So my Client does not get overloaded with to many request.

Is there a way to solve this with rabbitmq or do i have to change to some other framework?

Comment: How do you implement the client? Does it poll? Then it is up to the client to determine when to poll.

Comment: @LutzHorn I want to implement a publish/subscribe scenario. Does this change anything or do I have to make sure that my client has to manage everything?

Answer (score 2):

Any time you ask for assistance about RabbitMQ (or any software), you *must* provide information about what versions of software you are using, and what client libraries. That way the people who are assisting you can do so effectively.

Your client should consume from the queue using the `basic.consume` method. Set the channel's "prefetch" value to the maximum number of unacknowledged messages you wish for that consumer to receive at once (you can set it to `1` if you only want one message at a time). Then, do your work and only acknowledge the messages after the desired amount of time has elapsed.

Be certain that this does not result in messages accumulating in queues. You will [monitor](https://www.rabbitmq.com/monitoring.html) your RabbitMQ installation, right?

Comment: I have not implemented anything yet... I was looking for some solutions, so I have no fixed version number or libraries. Only requirement is rabbitmq.  I also set the prefetch value in my rabbitmq GUI or do I have to set it somewhere else? I am asking because I need to know, if I can change that value also in production mode, when i go online.

Comment: Please take the time to read and do the RabbitMQ tutorials, and read the documentation on rabbitmq.com. Both will answer most of your questions.